# How to get rid of a smartcard certificate "user" in my Windows 11 login screen?

Tags: windows, certificate, smartcard

I installed a smartcard reader and a smartcard certificate used to sign my company's documents in my system. To my surprise, the smartcard certificate became a "user" in my computer's sign-in screen.

I looked for the user in the users settings, but it doesn't show there.

I'd love to get rid of it as it seems to get precedence over my user even when the computer locks the screen up by inactivity.

Has anyone seen this and knows how to remove it? I'd like to keep the certificate functionality within browser to sign documents digitally, though.

Comment: Try and remove the certificate from the machine. As a method to avoid the user from appearing, that would require your company’s Administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm the administrator, but, anyway, removing the certificate didn't work.